# GCP: How do I use personal account during development instead of a JSON key of a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So, if I'm running a NodeJS script in a Compute Engine VM, then it'll pick up the credentials attached to this VM with this code:

```js
const pubSubClient = new PubSub()
```

If I'm running the same script locally and using a JSON key of a service account, then my code will look like this:

```js
const pubSubClient = new PubSub({keyFilename: './path-to-key.json', projectId: 'my-project-id'})
```

And what if I want to follow the [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-using-and-managing-service-accounts#development) and use my personal account during local development?
I login:

```sh
gcloud auth login
```

Now what? How do I pass the access to my NodeJS script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gcloud auth application-default login`. That command create a JSON file in the "well-known" location and the Google Cloud client libraries are able to find the file and then to use your user credentials.

Of course, your user account must be granted on the services to be able to use them.